# Access to GTK4 Widgets in C Using Gnome Builder

Tags: gnome, gtk4

I'm fairly new to coding for Linux, and haven't done a lot of GUI programming.  I've run into problems using Gnome Builder and programmatic access to UI widgets.

How the heck to you access a widget (built in a UI file and instantiated by widget templates in the *-window.c source file) to do anything with the widget?  I could use gtk_builder calls in GTK3 to access widgets, but the GTK4 model is completely different, and I haven't found useful information that describes or demonstrates how to do it.

Comment: One question at a time please. [ask]

Comment: I went overboard with my question initially...I've fixed that and focused on my primary issue.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways of doing this in GTK (both 3 and 4) with UI files:

- Parse the UI definition using something like [`gtk_builder_new_from_resource()`](https://docs.gtk.org/gtk4/ctor.Builder.new_from_resource.html). You can then use API like `gtk_builder_get_object()` to fetch the widgets you want by their `id` attribute
- Use composite templates like [`gtk_widget_class_bind_template_child()`](https://docs.gtk.org/gtk4/func.widget_class_bind_template_child.html). You can find an example of how to do this in the [second chapter](https://developer.gnome.org/documentation/tutorials/beginners/getting_started/content_view.html) of the [GNOME beginners tutorial](https://developer.gnome.org/documentation/tutorials/beginners.html)

Usually, the second option is preferred, as it tends to lead to less boilerplate code

Comment: Thanks.  That’s very helpful - and more useful than the GTK4 tutorial.  The GNOME tutorial parallels the GTK tutorial, but is definitely more accessible.  I hadn’t delved into the GNOME tutorial much because it started out looking a lot like the GTK tutorial…